# Thought bubbles in Yosemite

Tags: macos

When using Preview my Yosemite does NOT have the thought bubble option.. Is it a problem or does Yosemite not offer the thought bubble as Lion did.
I can get the speech bubble no problem.

Comment: It is no longer there. It was all the way till Mavericks, but then someone decided to remove them.